# How to display multiple table/chart in jupyter cells using panda?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Emphasis : I am looking for a way to display multiple tables or charts from a cell.

I have the following code where I have a table and a chart (and a few more) that I would like to display all those visuals in the out put shell after running it.

I tried importing `matplotlib` and `plt.show()` but they don't seem to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

tab = [[49.0,35.5,26.7,17.5], [46.7,34.0,26.0,17.1]]
tab = list(map(list, zip(*tab)))

tab_DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(tab, columns=["Mass(g)", "Volume(mL)"])
tab_DataFrame.head()
plt.show()
ax1 = tab_DataFrame.plot.line(x="Mass(g)", y="Volume(mL)",style='-o')
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: Works for me too. By the way, why have you used `plt.show()` twice?

Comment: Sorry about late reply. It only shows the last table. What I want is to create a visual and to display it one after another. Kinda like multiple print() statement but for visuals.